# Submitting comments with PHP (cURL)

Tags: php, web, curl

```
<?php 
$mycurl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($mycurl, 
    [
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://example.com", 
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE, 
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 4, 
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE, 
        CURLOPT_POST => TRUE, 
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => ["Name" => "Example", "Email" => "Example@gmail.com", "Comment" => "Example"]
    ]
);
$result = curl_exec($mycurl);
curl_close($mycurl); ?>
```

My code is wrong I know, I just want learn PHP.
How can I fix my code?
I want really simple thing.
I just want to comment on the website with the information I sent.

Comment: What doesn't work and what do you need to be fixed?

Comment: If you're attempting to comment on a website that's not your own, they most likely have some sort of protection to STOP you from doing this. I'd suggest using the form like any other user.

Answer (score 0):

https://example.org does not support comments. maybe try curling a service that actually support comments instead, like [Discord](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#create-message).

Comment: I know it was just a example :)